# Send scheduled email based on users conditions (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, queue, schedule, laravel-artisan

I faced with issue, that i can't solve by myself. Maybe someone can help me. Will be very appreciate.
So, I need to send scheduled email based on users conditions that store in database. 
For example, user's choice:
1. every 1,2,3...> hours/ days/ month at 12.00/13.00/14.00...>send email with record from database.
2. If user chose frequency (immediately) then mail send immediately, if postpone -> just checks last sent email.
After running command php artisan schedule:run, mail sends but I don’t know which logic I can use to add all conditions that i need, and where exactly I should put this logic. And not sure if it's even possible.
Thanks!

My structure now:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->call(function()
        Mail::to(‘mymail@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmailMailable());}



namespace App\Mail;
class SendEmailMailable extends Mailable
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public function build()
    {
        $data = [
            'type' => request()->type,
            'type2' => Setting::all()->pluck('type')->last(),
            'from' => request()->from,
            'from2' => Setting::all()->pluck('from')->last(),
            'to' => request()->to,
            'to2' => Setting::all()->pluck('to')->last(),
            'subject' => request()->subject,
            'subject2' =>Setting::all()->pluck('subject')->last(),
            'header' => request()->message_header,
            'header2' => Setting::all()->pluck('message_header')->last(),
            'errors' => request()->errors,
            'errors2' => Setting::all()->pluck('errors')->last(),
            'footer' => request()->message_footer,
            'footer2' => Setting::all()->pluck('message_footer')->last(),
        ];
        if(Setting::all()->where('frequence','=','direct')->latest()->first()) {
        return $this->view('mail.mail',$data);
        }
        else{
            die;
}}}

namespace App\Jobs;
class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
public function handle()
{
Mail::to(‘mymail@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmailMailable());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, [we can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Corrected, sorry

Comment: Ok, it seems, second question about frequency I solved:

 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function()
        {
            $frequence = Setting::all()->last()->pluck('frequence');
               if($frequence->last() == 'direct'){
            Mail::to('v.brilyak@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmailMailable());
        }
        else{
           echo Setting::all()->pluck('created_at');
        }
        });
    }
But how add another conditions (about time etc.) I don't know. 
Any ideas?